# What is wrong with my AJAX login management code? login.php is working, but ajax.js wont

Tags: php, jquery, authentication

What is wrong with my AJAX login management code?
When I try to login using my username and password, it goes perfectly with PHP, but my AJAX code wont to be work at all! What is the problem?

(NOTE: I'm new in jQuery and AJAx)

I have this code for index.php:

```
<html>
    <head><title>Login form</title></head>
    <body>

        <form id="myForm" action="testlogin.php" method="post">
        username: <input type="text" name="username"> <br />
        password: <input type="password" name="password"> <br />
        <button id="submit">Login</button>
        </form>
        <div id="ack"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.0.2.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="testajax.js"></script>

    </body>


</html>
```

And I have this code for testlogin.php:

```
<?php require_once("includes/connection.php"); ?> // starting the session.

<?php

$username = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST["username"]);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string( ($_POST["password"]));

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users2 WHERE (username='$username' AND password='$password')";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($res);

if($res === FALSE) {
    die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
}    

if( $row[0] > 0)
echo "Login Successful";
else
    echo "Failed To Login";
?>

<?php include("includes/footer.php"); ?> //closing the session
```

finally I have this testajax.js code:

```
$ ("button#submit") .click(function() {
   if ( $( "#username") .val() == "" || $( "#password") .val() == "" ) 
    $("div#ack") .html("Please enter both username and password");
    else
$.post ($("#myForm") .attr("action"),
$ ("#myForm :input") .serializeArryay(),
function(data) {
    $("div#ack") .html(data);

});    

   $("#myForm") .submit(function) {
       return false;
   }
});
```

Comment: Try looking in your network console to see what's going on with the request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this:

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($('input[name="username"]').val() == "" || $('input[name="password"]').val() == "") 
        $("#ack").html("Please enter both username and password");
    else
        $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize())
              .done(function(data) { $("#ack").html(data); })
              .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                  alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
              });
});
```

I fixed your spacing (may have happened when you copy and pasted) and cut your code down a bit.

When you submit the form it will either be successful and run `.done(...)` or it will fail and run `.fail(...)`. This should help you work out exactly where the script is failing.

Comment: There's nothing happened in either correct password or incorrect one!

Comment: I used the updated one, and this was the error: `ReferenceError: data is not defined
[Break On This Error]  

.done(function() { $("div#ack").html(data); })`

Comment: @MRAN - I made a correction a few hours ago, change `.done(function()` to `.done(function(data)` and it will work.